# How can I find meaning in 40 hr/week job

Tags: work-life-balance, workplace-rhythm

I've been a full-time software developer for the past 3 years, since graduating with a Computer Science degree. I initially had a lot of passion for this field - I used to spend my free time writing all kinds of things (artificial intelligence for various board games, a ray-tracing 3d renderer, mods for various computer games, etc...), a passion which grew the more I learned. I loved knowing this stuff.

The thing is, I was home-schooled before university and I would often be free by noon (okay, criticize my grade-school education if you want, I still graduated university with a perfect 4.0 gpa, so my parents must have done something right). I never had many friends, and I'd spend most of every day in my room, just keeping myself occupied (playing games, programming, watching tv, building neat things with my construction sets, reading). Hence, "normal life" for me is very slow-paced.

University was damned stressful to me since I wasn't used to the ridiculously huge workload, but having 3 months vacation in the summer, then another month in the winter, allowed me to sort of recuperate from that and give my mind a "reset". It was also fun and exciting looking forward to a completely new semester, of courses of my own choosing, after the summer.

This programming job though... well, objectively it's the best I could hope for. Friendly coworkers, almost never any overtime, pays really well - but it's tedious and dull as hell. It's also getting really hard to keep up with technology (which is now seriously impacting my productivity). The absolute last thing I want to do after programming all day long, every single day of my life, is learn more about programming. The passion I once had is now totally dead.

I'm tired of this, very burned out. The measly 2 weeks of vacation I get per year is nowhere near enough to really "reset". What the hell is the point of going on living when you're whole life revolves around the office? Having to restrict life solely to evenings and weekends only, for the next several decades until I can retire, is just so damned depressing when, for most of my life before, I actually owned most of my life.

Now, I feel like my employer owns me, but because I have a "good job" (according to my dad, and society in general I guess) I'm not allowed to complain.

My question is:  Considering my above described objections with the conventional work schedule and preferred lifestyle, what can I, as a young and competent professional do to find more meaning and motivation with the said arrangement?  For example, should I consider looking for a different career path or discuss my preferences with my manager to find mutually agreeable terms under which I will find work-life balance as well as be a productive team member?

Comment: Related: [How do I request an alternate/non-traditional schedule?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/27097/17125)

Comment: There is **big difference** between your current work life and your college/home schooling life, that is, **you are getting paid**.

Comment: Well first thing is to find a job that you enjoy so the 40 hrs (and some people regularly do much more) isn't a chore.  Also there are 168 hrs in a week, take out work and sleep and there are 72 hrs for you to do something that makes life worthwhile, even allowing for food/family etc there's plenty of time if you want it.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27167/discussion-on-question-by-kgreen-how-do-people-handle-working-40-hours-per-week).

Comment: Aaaaaand here is Bertrand Russell [chiming in](http://www.zpub.com/notes/idle.html) on the subject

Comment: I appreciate all of the advice and different viewpoints. Thank you! My "free time" per week is closer to 45 hrs than 72. I commute an hour each way (the neighborhoods near my workplace are quite bad), and lunch isn't counted in the 8 hours, so I leave at 7am and get home around 5:30pm, dinner/household chores until 6:30pm, then I get ready for bed at 10pm, hence in a typical day I have 3.5 hours, total, to enjoy. I just never understood how 8+ hours in front of a screen every day is okay and expected if it's for work, but 2-3 is considered grossly excessive if it's for enjoyment.

Comment: @TheWanderingDevManager Full time roles is never 72 hours free time, more like 40-50.  40+5(0.5*2*5, travel)+56(8*7, sleep)+7 (1*7, food/cook)+3.5(0.5*7, cleaning/hygeine)= 168-111.5 = 56.5 ***and this is a maximum***

Comment: @KGreen I'm the exact same as you man, the exact same. I sit at work wishing I could learn, but all I'm doing is mundane crap. That is why I'm leaving my job, using my frugality to go to Korea and then seeing where I can get from there. Might end up back in Australia, maybe back in London... but I know for sure my current job isn't something I wanna be in for the next few years.

Comment: @insidesin - depends on what you prioritse.  I may only need 25 mins a day for food, but take 10 hrs (2*5) for commute.  The point is not EXACTLY how long you have, but even in your example you have more time than you work to do something else.  My point is work only dominates your life if you let it, you can have a full life outside work without doing the Tim Ferris 4hr work week fantasy.  Most people waste time, and sit in front of the tube (screen?) and then say "work dominates my life", when it's not even 25% of it.

Comment: But you can't exactly do much with the hours you are given, unless you are happy spending most of the time by yourself. 2 days out of 7 where you can spend outdoors in the sun is not fun. I honestly don't know how some people work, then spend, then work, then spend. I work, save as much as I can and then go on long periods of holiday. I am quite cheap, but my moto is the less I spend today, the less I have to work. Fun can be had without paying a lot. I do completely understand you. I personally only hate that I work in London, where most of my money goes towards.. working in London. :(

Comment: why hasn't the question been reopened after my edit ?

Comment: Meaning is often made. Take joy in doing something difficult well. Take joy in improving either the product or the process. Take joy in teaching and learning from co-workers.

Comment: The question was edited by a moderator to be more relevant to this website. I personally don't care about meaning / purpose / etc... I just am so burned out that I often feel like life isn't worth living - life was great when I had the whole day to myself, but it seems in adulthood we are lucky when we can have the last 2-3 hours in the evening - everything else is just pointless obligations we fulfill just for the privilege to continue existing in this rat race. That's what I'm having difficulty coping with.

Comment: "objectively it's the best I could hope for" "it's tedious and dull as hell".  These two comments seem to contradict each other...

Comment: Time is one's most precious resource; one can make more money, but one can't buy more time. I know it's been years since you asked this question, but you may find answers—or, simply, solace—in Erik Dietrich's great book, _Developer Hegemony._ He also blogs at https://daedtech.com

Comment: @scaaahu it's not like you can use the money to buy your lost time back. I feel the same as OP, 8 hour workdays are sucking all of the enjoyment out of my life. It's not about the job itself, it's about having to be at work for 9 hours a day and then getting a grand total of one hour to myself every day.

Comment: @HugoZink You can always quit your job to have the enjoyment of your life back.

Comment: @scaaahu that isn't an option, we all need money to live.

Comment: @HugoZink Here you go. That's exactly my point. You can try to balance the work and the life. But, the reality is that you sell your time and enjoyment of the life to exchange for the salary. Don't forget, there are many people in other parts of the world who can't get good job opportunities. In my location, Taiwan, an entry level programmer only makes about US$1000 a month.

Comment: @scaaahu you're missing my point. My original point is that the fact that OP is earning money will not make him feel any better about his situation. Most of that money goes to expenses, and what good is leftover money if you're too exhausted to be able to enjoy it? It doesn't ease the pain one bit.

Answer (score 36):

I have largely the same experience as yourself (except the homeschooling bit). Did great in college, enjoyed college, used to spend much of my free time programming artificial neural networks and writing software. Started work at a software company and my urge to do that kind of stuff died.

They weren't horrible, the hours weren't bad but it was still killing me. My girlfriend was starting to worry about my health. Days of staring at stack traces combined with the push to spend evenings learning about frameworks that might once have fascinated me but which now just make me feel more burned out and sad.

*A job doesn't have to be horrible to eat at your soul.*

Jobs which depress you don't have to involve horrible bosses or 100 hour weeks. Sometimes it can simply be the job slowly turning your brain to soft jelly.

After a few years of that I moved to a different job and it made a world of difference. I'm back to writing code for the joy of it again.

Small things can contribute towards being generally unhappy and can make a job eat far more than 40 hours because you need longer to unwind.

For example some things can be common in junior programming roles:

1. Okay, but not great pay.
2. Lack of control of your own work.

   The senior people poaching the interesting work before you ever get a shot at it.
3. An office where nobody is hostile or horrible but never the less you say "Hi" to the guy across from you and "Bye" in the evening without much more social interaction.
4. Lack of classes/learning as part of the job rather something you're expected to spend your evenings and weekends doing.
5. Inflexible hours.
6. Commute times which can eat 10+ more hours per week in many large urban areas.

I moved to a new job which fixed many of these and other relatively minor issues and started smiling on the way to work again.

You likely have your own list of things which are getting to you.

40 hours can eat your life or it can be a light burden depending on the workplace.

So I'd advise finding somewhere else. It's not worth your sanity. Give it a little time, learn from your current job, make sure to remember the things they're doing right, keep on good terms but try looking for a different role that interests you more.

Comment: This answer is not relevant to the OP, since the OP did not state any of the issues you experienced (no control over work, seniors stealing work, inability to connect with colleagues) but instead was just complaining about working 40 hours a week.

Comment: They are however relatively common in junior programming roles. I wouldn't have listed some of these issues until I'd experienced another workplace and realized they'd been part of the problem.  Either way they're just examples of the kind of things which can contribute to an otherwise pleasant workplace being oppressive and depressing. They can be the sort of thing that makes even a 40 hour week horrible. I'm including them because the OP reminds me of how that job made me feel.

Comment: I find it ironical that the post that begins by advising "Ignore the preachy posters. They're just bitter" shows more bitterness than any other answer, complaining about things the OP is not having trouble with.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan When I wrote this the existing replies were chastising the OP for having the temerity to be unhappy with his lot and saying the problem was with him rather than possibly with anything else whatsoever.

Comment: I appreciate the response, Murphy. In fact, 3, 4, 5, and 6 do apply to me (well, my hours are flexible-ish. I can come in an hour later if I want, but then I'd have to stay an hour later). I know I need to find another job, I just don't know how because I don't really have any skills in other fields, and definitely not the energy to attend night classes to obtain them. Hell, I couldn't keep up with coursera classes I took for fun.

Comment: @KGreen You might be surprised, programmers can do well in quite a lot of programming-associated fields where programming intersects with sciences, engineering, buisness etc once you have a quite modest level of experience you may find you can move into something else that interests you. You don't have to abandon the entire field. Good luck to you though.

Answer (score 22):

If you still have enough money if it is only 75% or even 50% of your current salary, you can think about working part-time which means 30h or even 20h per week.

Having worked six hours per day a week after a standard 40h week I can say that you really feel the difference. You are fresher, you are less sick and you work more intense. I would even say that I would not reduce it further even if offered, but your mileage may vary.

The whole problem is your working environment as TJennings answer indicates. There are unspoken assumptions like that it is unfair, that you are spoiled, that you have still so much time, that people *need* to work hard (or the standard: Other people have it much worse) etc. etc. often convieniently ignoring that you earn much less money. Depending on your culture you may see more or less resistance, so I cannot give you general advice how to approach your employer.

Anyway: It is your decision what your goals in life are.

ADDITION:
First of all, there are people who thrive under hard-working conditions. They can and *want* work 80 hours a week, they are ambitious and they want to acquire status symbols and climb up the social ladder. And they would be very unhappy if they could not work.

That said, some people gives the impression that 40 hours are at least normal, most people live fulfilling lives with it and if you find that too strenous, you are mollycoddled and do not know real work.

The problem is "most people". In our country we had a time where young people had a compulsory social year and so I did short time in an old-age home.

Me and other people noticed that some of the most important and frequent regrets of old people are [that they did not a life true to themselves and that they worked too hard](http://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/2012/feb/01/top-five-regrets-of-the-dying) !

Given that I hope you understand that I think the "most people live fulfilling lives etc." argument is...a bit...unconvincing.

I know that there dire circumstances like supporting a family or other people does sometimes leave no options, but your conscience will know that and it will be no trouble later. But decide with wisdom what you want from **your** life, what other people do with their life and think how life should be is not your concern.

Comment: Some of my friends go with this approach, 4 day weeks can be a good compromise which can make things much more manageable.

Comment: In the UK part-time programming positions are almost unheard of, so that might not be an option everywhere.

Comment: @domen That is the culture part which I mentioned in the second last sentence. Yes, it may be not (easily) achieveable, so in fact it really depends how far are you wiling to go (move, 4 x 10h days, another job may be other options). But I have the suspicion that many people are simply not willing to test their boundaries because they are fearing social ostracization and excuse their lack of trying with "It is impossible".

Comment: I'd love to work part time. Problem is - it isn't 1/2 hours for 1/2 pay. It would be closer to 1/2 hours for 1/8 the pay (that's not a typo - part time jobs are nearly always minimum wage, or close to it), plus I'd be losing some significant company benefits (namely free medical and dental insurance).

Comment: @KGreen, would it be the case with 30 hours a week too? Because it is a good compromise. 8 hours a day and 6 hours a day makes the difference. And it could still be acceptable for the employer,

Answer (score 18):

I think many people go through that phase. Here's some advice from my experience (in no particular order):

1. Have you considered moving abroad?

   I think there's a lot difference in working culture between countries. 
   I have worked as a programmer in 4 different countries in Europe, and the normal working conditions I encountered are 35-40 hours per week with 5-6 weeks of holidays.
2. Have you thought about looking for a better company?

   I think that a good tech company understands your need to develop your skills and treat the learning as **a part of your job**, not something you do in the evening after hours.

   I have had companies sent me to conferences (and pay for it) / give me a couple days off to study (in addition to normal holidays) / pay for my programming certifications / send me to language lessons, courses etc.

   This is all possible with a good company that supports your developement.
3. Have you tried organising your day better / more efficient?

   There are many ways to save some precious time. Some of them include:

   - Rent a flat near your office, so you save time on commute
   - Use some time to plan your day / week ahead. Run many errands at once.
   - Prepare meals for the whole day (or a couple days) at once, so you spend less time cooking
4. Can you take some time off in between jobs?

   When I changed jobs I often took a month off in between them to travel and charge my batteries.
5. Have you considered freelance work or running your own company?

   I honestly believe that office work and 9 to 5 jobs are not suited for everyone.

   When you're your own boss, you set the rules. Want to go home early? No problem. Need extra holidays? Just make sure you can afford it and go.

Comment: +1 for constructive suggestions, and also bringing in the issue of working conditions by country. At a guess OP is in the USA and only gets 2 weeks a year holiday; in the UK 5 is the norm, and some European countries more than that.

Comment: I was reading [this](http://www.amazon.com/Thats-Not-English-Britishisms-Americanisms/dp/1592408850) and it's interesting how much more seriously they take their "holiday" in comparison to America. I obviously live in the wrong country lol

Comment: Thank you for the reply. 1) I have seriously considered moving to Europe, but I don't know anyone there, nor how to apply to jobs there, nor even what companies to apply to (I don't want to pigeonhole myself into another yet programmer role I might hate, while being stuck in a foreign country with no family or friends at all and without speaking the language). 2) By any objective measure, I am in a great company. Programming just isn't for me anymore, but it's all I know. I guess I just don't know how to find a field I'd like that wouldn't burn me out. No one prepared me for this.

Comment: @KGreen In most of the countries capitals you'll find english is a common language. In fact in our countries capital (Belgium) because of the language barrier between the french / dutch speaking parts, most meetings are simply in English. Or failing that in "speak your own language, just make sure everyone understands" mixture of languages.

Comment: @KGreen: Don't worry too much - the ability to manage your time, handle stress, make good decisions and career choices comes with experience. This is precisely the kind of wisdom that makes veteran employees valuable. The good thing is that you can learn it too if you keep a cool head and do your best. The truth is no one can fully prepare you for life - not school, not TV, not even your parents. Be proactive and think about solutions to your problems rather than things you can't or won't do. I know you can do it! Good luck!

Answer (score 14):

40 hours a week is pretty far from `your whole live revolves around the office`, and if you've got `friendly coworkers, almost never any overtime`, you've probably got vastly more free time and a more pleasant workplace than others who don't feel like their whole life revolves around the office.

Your life doesn't stop while you're at the office, and resume when you leave, unless you absolutely hate your job and everyone at it, in which case get out and find something else. You can keep up with technology at the office, and if your passion is dead, that's not the fault of the job - It's because you only enjoy something when you're doing it as a hobby.

"Work to live, not live to work" is the mantra, and it seems like you're actually doing a pretty good job of it if you're working 40 hours in a good job. There's 168 hours in a week, you spend less than a quarter of that in the office and around the same sleeping. It sounds to me like your upbringing has simply spoiled you for choice in being able to do what you like whenever you like, with a work-life balance skewed too far in the 'life' direction, and you're having trouble adjusting to more conventional scheduling.

To answer the question, people "handle working 40+ hours a week" by not viewing their work with a sense of resentment that it's taking up their time. The problem isn't the working culture, it's your mindset towards work.

Comment: The end of this answer sounds judmental. The problem is the inadequacy between his culture, education and the current typical work organisation in our society. Nobody is to blame. And although I agree it is more likely that the OP will eventually have to adapt, arrangments can be made, so that the OP finds a balance that satifies him. Not likely, but still.

Comment: @Puzzled It wasn't intended to be judgmental so much as to suggest that he had a fortunate upbringing that unfortunately didn't do well to prepare him for the pressures of a modern workplace, no different from any other culture shock one experiences when changing into a different world culture.

Comment: I quite agree with your answer, not its wording. And Thorsen S. also has a point with part-time working that could be a good arrangment if the OP is ready to give up a part of his income.

Comment: This answer may sound a bit judgemental but it seems like the OP has been a little mollycoddled and has false expectations. Assuming from the mention of gpa they are from US, in western unis the workload is notoriously low-medium.  You don't have to work all day in a job you hate and that may be part of it but a 40 hour week is normal and you will have to get used to that whatever you do. Remember programming is a tool, it is the things that you do with it that are fun or not. If you context switch on the subject then it'll be easier to find business logic boring but then go and play with AI.

Comment: @JamesRyan This is a false assumption. It may be that there is a strong work ethic and peer pressure in the USA, but if you (and your life partner) are living frugally, do not need the newest toys and have no monetary obligations (house, children)  and have therefore more than enough money, why do you should work 40 hours ? Time is limited and not interchangeable. Can you imagine that you regret on your deathbed that you spent not enough working hours in your job ?

Comment: @ThorstenS. each employee carries an overhead to employers. Part-time employees cost more to cover the same amount of man hours so full-time will always be preferable. The type of jobs available part time tend to be non-career, lower paying jobs. Don't forget tech hobbies cost money. Contracting might be an option but that comes with its own additional burdens.  If the OP is suffering culture shock from 'normal' working then I'm not sure they would be adaptable enough, although its a skill that could be learned.

Comment: @ThorstenS. The key point though is that it's not the time that makes a job bad.  If something is reasonably enjoyable and engaging you can do it all day long.

Comment: I'd argue with the last point, I had a very different upbringing but still hit many of the same feelings at one of my workplaces. Some jobs can suck all that is good out of your life.

Comment: @JamesRyan: In the USA, **Part-Time usually means "no benefits"**, therefor no cost to the employer for health care insurance and other very expensive things. This is the cause of the current "war" of employers trying to classify more people as PT and the government trying to get health care for more people so that they do not bankrupt the insurers and hospitals. Additionally, a PT employee must pay for their own health care insurance (I do) which is more than half of the amount I pay for rent. So, it is not a slam dunk either way. Eventually, I think *everyone* will become a "Contractor".

Comment: There may be 168 hours in a week, but we sleep through a third of the time.  That leaves 112 waking hours on average.  From that we subtract time for banalities such as eating, washing, grocery shopping, housework.  A 40h/week job, plus commute time of 5 -10 (or more) hours a week means that the largest part of your (awake) life is indeed in the office.

Comment: This answer is inaccurate. Your waking life *does* revolve around the office. You spend roughly 9 hours in the office (you're not getting paid through lunch), and you also might spend 2 hours a day (usually more!) commuting to and from work.

Answer (score 8):

It sounds like you are trying to do a job which is your hobby, but what you have found is that your hobby became your job and you are not left with a hobby any more. Fortunately it sounds like you have some other hobbies ("playing games, ... watching tv, building neat things with my construction sets, reading"). Maybe you should focus more on these.

I also found myself in a similar situation - when I had been coding all day I didn't enjoy going home to do some more coding "for fun". So I stopped and found some different activities.

Ironically as I have grown more into my role I have found that I am doing less coding, with more time spent in meetings, fleshing out requirements, helping more junior developers, etc. When this is the case those are the days when I feel like I want to get "back into the code" and I am more likely to work on pet projects.

As a very practical solution to your problem, some companies allow employees to do x% projects <sup>[[1]](http://googleblog.blogspot.co.uk/2006/05/googles-20-percent-time-in-action.html)[[2]](http://www.forbes.com/sites/johnkotter/2013/08/21/googles-best-new-innovation-rules-around-20-time/)</sup> (typically x is about 5-20) where the employee is free to develop whatever they want in that x% of their time. You could see if you can read up on x% projects and come up with a compelling reason why your company might want to allow you/your team/all devs to do an x% project. This would allow you to do some of the tinkering that you enjoy, but can be in the main part of the day when you are most fresh.

Comment: People asked me why I did not study Electronics in school and make that my career... This reason! I still love Electronics and Radio, but burned out on programming after a few years. I did what interested me most at the time, then moved on. It is said that most people will have 6 "careers" in their lifetime, so just choose another one!

Answer (score 6):

> how do people live full, enjoyable lives despite having their lives
>   restricted solely to evenings (when too tired and stressed out to want
>   to do anything but play a mindless game for a couple hours before
>   bed), and weekends?

Most people don't have the same upbringing you had. And (perhaps consequently?) most people don't have the same outlook on work and life that you do.

Most people I know aren't so stressed out after work that they don't do anything but play mindless games. For me, that never happened.

Most people I know find at least some parts of their work rewarding. For most of my career, I have found my work very rewarding.

Most people I know have a social life that they enjoy, at least part of which is at work. That has always been the case for me.

**Most people I know are capable of living full, enjoyable lives despite the normal demands of work.**

Perhaps it's just maturity (sometimes new graduates feel this way until they have adjusted to the working world). Perhaps it's upbringing. Perhaps it's just personality. Perhaps you just haven't found the right job or career that would be sufficiently rewarding. Perhaps you need to consider alternate job styles where you have more time off (such as contracting). Perhaps you need some counselling to deal with personal/emotional/physical issues.

"how do people live full, enjoyable lives?" Most do. Some do so immediately, others take a while and have to experiment with different careers/jobs/job styles to get there. It's hard for some young folks who haven't ever had any real-world work experience to get it right the first time. Some never do.

Comment: +1 for experimenting. I personally left high school and tried jobs as mail-man, line-worker, delivery guy before I ended up taking night and later on full-time classes to get into ICT. We have so much information available to us nowadays but so little time to truly find out what life is like as an adult before we're supposed to become one. Having a sheltered life OP might even benefit from just interacting with other people not in his immediate social circle.

Comment: I'm a bit disillusioned to read that someone could be burned out after 3 years of 40hr work weeks in ICT. It really shows a lack of preparation for work life that seems to permeate my generation. I wish more of us spent a few years doing menial labor. And less stigma on menial jobs. If the OP's parents had have him try a summer job at a super market for a few years he might have a completely different perspective on life.

Comment: Whose life is he living though - "most people"s' or his own? It's kind of irrelevant that most people are capable of doing xyz if he can't. The 40 hour work week doesn't suit everybody, and it's certainly not the only way to make a living

Comment: @Reaces: One thing that "burned me out" as a developer after a few years was the lack of social interaction: I was one of 3 programmers using the language I knew (There were 30 other programmers) and I worked mainly on independent projects. So I was not even going to meetings or talking over development issues! Isolation is not conducive to happiness.

Comment: @Roy While I can appreciate the advice that people need to thread their own paths, it does not make the statement that most people are just fine with 40hr work weeks any less valid. The vast majority of us have jobs we enjoy, that earn us enough money to further finance activities we enjoy. Stating what the majority experiences helps put in context what the repercussions for being part of the minority might be. And the financial deficit is important, even more so when you become more and more independent.

Comment: @nocomprende: Sounds like something you can easily bring up to your management, and shouldn't be endured to the point of a burn out... We have several people working on independent technologies here as well, and they join the stand up meetings of our team, where they can explain their issues and setbacks when needed. If you feel isolated, speak up. It's not because you program in MAGIC that people who deal only in C# can't relate to your problems.

Comment: @Reaces: I did ask for help at the time (over 15 years ago) and tried to change to another job in the company. But the company had only about 100 people, and was bought and sold to other companies several times while I worked there. Later I ran a retreat center, and also burned out and was isolated. I worked on an assembly line for half a year - isolated, no one worked near me (I did sometimes train others). Being a teacher / instructor mostly works, but my "real career" (as two girlfriends have said) is not open to me : ) Some people are just *different*, so the usual solutions will not work.

Answer (score 4):

I can completely empathise with you OP, I'm in almost exactly the same situation where taught myself web development and programming because I enjoyed it and it was my hobby. I then turned that hobby into my profession after university and after a couple of jobs like yours I'm now likewise burnt out from tedious and dull work. This seems to be pretty common in the software development industry - probably because the industry is largely full of self-taught developers who learnt because it was fun, not because they had to.

The issue is when you are programming for a hobby you have free reign over what you do and when you do it. Suddenly when you work professionally you have deadlines to meet and specs to follow. You can't do what you want and even your personal programming style might be overridden by the project's programming guidelines.

Luckily there are a lot of options out there in this industry for people like you and I - 40+ hour a week jobs in cubicles are not the only way you can be a developer. Freelancing is very common, as is remote working. Also since burn out is common in this industry some companies are starting to recognise this and work to mitigate it - I only work Monday-Thursday at my current job, for example. Or you might simply find that developing professionally is not for you, and it's best just to keep programming as a personal hobby/side job.